# Given that $|f(x,y)| \le x^{2}y^{2}$, prove that $f$ is differentiable at (0, 0).

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Given that $f : \mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a function such that $|f(x,y)| \le x^{2}y^{2}$ for all $(x,y) ∈ R^{2}$, prove that $f$ is differentiable at $(0, 0)$.

I know that I should show that there exists a plane : $L(x,y) = f(0,0) + c(x-0) + d(y-0)$;
such that $\lim \dfrac{R}{||(x,y)-(0,0)||} = 0$.  I don't understand how the inequality gives me the information that I need. Is it because $f$ is bounded by $x^{2}y^{2}$ (which is differentiable at $(0,0)$?

So I have to prove that $$\dfrac{|f(x,y) - [f(0,0) +f_x(0,0)x + f_y(0,0)y ]|}{||\sqrt{ x^{2}y^{2}}||}  = 0 $$

Can I make each term (i.e. $f(x,y)$, $f(0,0)$, $f_x(0,0)$, $f_y(0,0)$) less than $x^{2}y^{2}$? Then I get that the limit = 0, which proves the statement.  I'm just not sure whether I'm allowed to do that.

Comment: First of all, could you find the value of $f(0,0)$?

Comment: How could I do that without knowing what F is?

Comment: Ohhh because x^2y^2 = 0 at (0,0) so f must be 0 as well

Comment: Is there a way to calculate the patial derivatives as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $L(x,y) = f(0,0) + 0x + 0y = 0 + 0 = 0$, and observe that $f(0,0) = 0$, and $x^2y^2 \leq (x^2 +y^2)^2$. Thus:

$L = \dfrac{||f(x,y) - L(x,y)||}{||(x,y)||} \leq \dfrac{(x^2+y^2)^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = (x^2 + y^2)^{\frac{3}{2}} \to 0$ as $||(x,y)|| \to 0$. Thus the limit of $L$ is $0$, and $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$.